# Count tweets per day, weigh by 3 other columns in same table

Tags: mysql

(This is quite a long post, but the problem is I think easy to solve and I have a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58aa2/3) ready) Please consider the following table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
tweet_id sp100_id nyse_date   user_id class_id retweets quality follow
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1        2011-03-12  1       1        0        2.50    5.00
2        1        2011-03-13  1       2        2        2.50    5.00
3        1        2011-03-13  1       2        1        2.50    5.00
4        1        2011-03-13  2       2        0        0.75    1.00
5        1        2011-03-13  2       3        3        0.75    1.00
6        2        2011-03-12  2       2        3        0.75    1.00
7        2        2011-03-12  2       2        0        0.75    1.00
8        2        2011-03-12  1       3        5        2.50    5.00
9        2        2011-03-13  2       2        0        0.75    1.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The desired output from this table is a list per `sp100_id` per `_date` the amount of positive (class=2) and negative (class=3) tweets weighted per `retweets`, `quality` and `follow`:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sp100_id  nyse_date  pos-rt pos-quality pos-follow neg-rt neg-quality neg-follow
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         2011-03-11 0      0           0          0      0           0
1         2011-03-12 0      0           0          0      0           0
1         2011-03-13 3 (1)  5.75 (2)    11.00 (3)  3 (4)  0.75        1.00
2         2011-03-11 0      0           0          0      0           0
2         2011-03-12 3      1.50        10.00      5.00   2.50        2.50
2         2011-03-13 0      0.75        1.00       0      0           0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

On 2011-03-13, 3 positive tweets for sp100_id 1:

(1) 1 tweet retweeted 2 times, 1 tweets retweeted 1 time and 
    1 tweet retweeted 0 times = 1 x 2 + 1 x 1 + 1 x 0 = 3
(2) 2 tweets with quality 2.50 and 1 tweet with quality 0.75 =
    2 x 2.50 + 1 x 0.75 = 5.75
(3) 2 tweets with follow 5 and 1 tweet with follow 1 =
    2 x 5.00 + 1 x 1.00 = 11.00

On 2011-03-13, 1 negative tweets for sp100_id 1:

(4) 1 tweet retweeted 3 times = 1 x 3 = 3

etc...
```

I have a demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58aa2/3) with the necessary other tables (I need to link it to a daterange table because I also want to include recordsets with all zero's). I also have an output for my query, but I don't understand why it is different from the desired output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sp100_id  nyse_date  pos-rt pos-quality pos-follow neg-rt neg-quality neg-follow
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         2011-03-11 0      0           0          0      0           0
1         2011-03-12 3      2           2          5      3           5
1         2011-03-13 3      8           12         3      1           1
2         2011-03-11 0      0           0          0      0           0
2         2011-03-12 3      2           2          5      3           5
2         2011-03-13 3      8           12         3      1           1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't see where the problem lies. Do you? Your help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it wasn't returning expected values is because you need to also include `sp100.sp100_id = tweets.sp100_id` in the `LEFT JOIN` condition along with the date.

By only joining on the date, it will join on any date value in the table, regardless of `sp100_id`. This is why your resulting sums were being thrown off because for each `sp100_id`, it was including the values of all other `sp100_id`s in the `SUM()`s.

I also cleaned up your query a little bit (just in terms of aesthetics):

```
SELECT     a.sp100_id,
           b._date AS nyse_date,
           SUM(IF(c.class=2, c.retweets, 0)) AS 'pos-rt',
           SUM(IF(c.class=2, c.quality,  0)) AS 'pos-quality',
           SUM(IF(c.class=2, c.follow,   0)) AS 'pos-follow',
           SUM(IF(c.class=3, c.retweets, 0)) AS 'neg-retweet',
           SUM(IF(c.class=3, c.quality,  0)) AS 'neg-quality',
           SUM(IF(c.class=3, c.follow,   0)) AS 'neg-follow'
FROM       sp100 a
CROSS JOIN daterange b
LEFT JOIN  tweets c ON a.sp100_id = c.sp100_id 
                   AND b._date = c .nyse_date
GROUP BY   a.sp100_id, 
           nyse_date
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87ce8/10/0)

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see is your use of the `dec` datatype. I switched it to float and everything seems fine.

Am I missing some incorrect values?

You are missing some values for March 13 (the last line) when you did your math manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The output is indeed different when changing to float, but still incorrect. I don't believe there are any missing values in the manual output. For instance, on the last line `pos-rt` should be `0` because the one positive tweet that has been made that day, is retweeted `0` times. Also, there are no negative (`class=3`) tweets for `sp100_id` 2 on that date, so `neg-retweet`, `neg-quality` and `neg-follow` should all be `0` as well. Something else is wrong..most values are way off...